# UK tourist visa for my younger brother

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, family

I am working in the UK and want to sponsor my younger brother’s tourist visa, he works as a self employed person for my dad’s company which is not in his name. Since I am working, can I show my salary slips for his proof of funds and send him a visa invite or how much funds would he have to show?? I am worried his application might be rejected due to the fact that they might think he wants to stay back which is obviously not true

Comment: Why is it ‘obviously not true’? That is what you need to convince the ECO of, but it’s not ‘obvious’ from your question. If your brother’s profile is young, no family ties (= dependents), no prior travel history, *and* needs a financial sponsor to cover the costs of the trip, having family in the UK can count against him.

Answer (score 13):

While you may add your financials to prove you are able to support their visit, your brother still needs to show evidence of this financial situation, which is required to evaluate his ties to his country.

I don’t quite understand how he can be “self employed for your dad’s company”. Either he is self-employed, or he is salaried in your father’s company.

The second option is usually a lot better for establishing his situation, as long as:

- There are regular pay slips
- His wages are paid into his bank account
- Both match
- There are no other payments coming into his account
- He actually pays for all his own costs out of that account

Do that for 6 months, and you have a nice clear picture to present in the application: he has a job, he gets his wages, and all documents confirm the situation.

There are of course alternatives, but they can get quite a bit more complex to show unequivocally. No separation between business and personal accounts, irregular wages, cash payments, lack of pay slips or tax returns, missing expenses, all of that will quickly lead to refusals just because the ICO just can’t be have a clear picture. Paint the picture they want to see. For real, of course.